# How can I manage continuous bidirectional folder sync, *a la* Dropbox app?

Tags: sync, cloud

I have a folder on my laptop (Ubuntu Mate 16.04.3 LTS), and one on my desktop machine (Kubuntu 14.04.5 LTS), that I wish to sync, and because the laptop may be on any of several wifi connections (home, Starbuck's, my game shop, etc.) at a given time, I need to sync via a cloud service, but the folder I need to sync is too large for my Dropbox (I can pay for more Dropbox storage, but I'd prefer not to).

I've obtained sufficient space on Google Drive, and I have google-drive-ocamlfuse installed and confirmed working on both computers.  Unfortunately, google-drive-ocamlfuse doesn't sync local folders as the Dropbox app does; instead, it just makes the cloud folder look like a local folder, and access through the Internet is too slow to use directly for loading a large program (like a game).

I've installed Unison on both machines and created local folders to sync into, but it turns out only to operate when I open the software, wait for a protracted scan, and then click "Go" to complete the operation (and it doesn't seem to do that at all well; multiple attempts still had files in the cloud that wouldn't sync to my desktop machine).

How can I set up *continuous bidirectional sync* between two arbitary folders -- to work like Dropbox, that is?  Software that will sync two local folders, or a local folder and a network storage, ought to work, because google-drive-ocamlfuse makes the cloud storage look like a local folder.  I'd prefer a free or free and open solution for this, if possible.

Comment: You may use [Insync](https://www.insynchq.com/) for Google Drive. It works well, but non-free.

Comment: I'd obviously prefer a free or free/open solution here, but I'll keep that one in mind.

Comment: I know it has been a while. Did you ever find anything? I am looking for something similar that works with any WebDav server

Comment: I never did.  I was on Kubuntu 16.04 when I asked this; I'm now on Kubuntu 22.04 and no longer try to play games at Starbuck's, the game shop closed during the pandemic, and this question is largely moot for me at the moment.